# Python raw_input()

Tags: python

From the docs, raw_input() reads a line from input, converts it to a **string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

with that note,

```
a = 'testing: '
sep = '-'
c = raw_input('give me some args: ')          <--- giving 'a b c d'

def wrap( a, sep, *c):
    print a + sep.join(c)

wrap(a, sep, c)

str = 'a b c d'
print sep.join(str)
```

they should both print out the same thing but...

`print a + sep.join(c)`  gives **testing: a b c d**
`print sep.join(str)`    gives **a- -b- -c- -d**

why doesn't `sep.join()` works inside wrap function?

EDIT
changing from *c to c makes the output the same but this somewhat confuses me because i thought *c unpacks the args but when i print c, it give ms ('a b c d',) compared to a string of 'a b c d' so in a sense, it is combining them to a single tuple entity which is the opposite of unpacking?

or... it does not unpack string but only lists?

Comment: It unpacks when used in "active" code. When used in the argument list of a function, it means (roughly, very): this argument is the collection of all the parameters passed to the function which are not assigned to any other argument. Which allows you to pass a variable number of arguments to a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function `c` is a tuple of one element because of the splat (*), therefore the separator is never used.
In the main program, you're calling join on a string, which is split into its characters. Then you get as many istances of the separator as many charactes are there (minus one).

Comment: yes, i suppose i was confused on the fact that it would "unpack" the argument or a string in this case but it does the opposite. so i would actually have to have the raw_input() in a list instead of string in order to have the same effect which is a bit intriguing.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "the same effect"

Comment: the same effect = printing out the same thing

Answer (score 2):

join expects an array not a string so if you are trying to use the arguments as separate items you need to use `c = c.spilt(' ')` and get rid of the * in the `def wrap`.

To my surprise `sep.join(str)` is treating str as an array of chars hence the extra -s between letters and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
>>> wrap(a, sep, str)
testing: a b c d
```

is different from:

```
>>> wrap(a, sep, *str)
testing: a- -b- -c- -d
```

A string **is** a list of characters. You can change the function signature from `def wrap(a, sep, *c):` to `def wrap(a, sep, c):` and you should be fine.